# how to plot multiple curves with plotyy in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to draw a plot with 2 `Y` axes and one `X` axes. Its a 2-D line plot with y-axes on both left and right side.

There are multiple curves to be plotted.

For example:

```
x=1:20
% For Left Y axes
y1_1=randn(20,1)*1 + 0
y1_2=randn(20,1)*1 + 5
y1_3=randn(20,1)*1 + 10

% For Right Y axes
y2_1=randn(20,1)*1 + 20
y2_2=randn(20,1)*1 + 30
y2_3=randn(20,1)*1 + 40
```

How can I Draw this?

Answer (score 2):

You can supply several `Y`s for each x:

```
plotyy( x, [y1_1, y1_2, y1_3], x, [y2_1 ,y2_2, y2_3] );
```

should do the trick for you.

Comment: Nice +1 already. BTW, how do i know which one is specified by left and which one is right? All 6 of them is in different color. Will be great if 3 in one color and other 3 in another color

Comment: @Shai, How can I change the ranges of the y axes.  In case of a normal 2_D plot: axis([XMIN XMAX YMIN YMAX]). How about for the ployy case?

Comment: @DipankarNarayanan look at the examples [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html): you can get the axes handle of each of the plots and change the `ylim` properties of the specific axes handle.

Comment: To change the colour you can acccess to the `children` of each axes and set the `color` property: `a=plotyy( x, [y1_1, y1_2, y1_3], x, [y2_1 ,y2_2, y2_3] )` then `h=a(1);` and `set(get(h(1),'children'),'color','k','linewidth',2)`. Similar for the other.